# list unique values for each column in a data frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Suppose you have a very large input file in "csv" format. And you want to know the different values that occur in each column. How would you do that?

ex.

```
column1    column2    column3    column4
----------------------------------------
value11    value12    value13    value14
value21    value22    value23    value24
...
valueN1    valueN2    valueN3    valueN4
```

So I want my output to be something like:

`column1 has these values: value11, value21, ...valueN1`. but I don't need to see reoccurrences of the same value. I need this just to get an idea of what my data is all about.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let `dat` be your data frame after reading in the `csv` file, you can do

```
ulst <- lapply(dat, unique)
```

If you further want to know the number of unique values for each column, do

```
k <- lengths(ulst)
```

Comment: Or using `dplyr` ie. `dat %>% summarise_each(funs(n_distinct))`

Comment: I'm curious, can the dplyr function be adapted to not just count the distinct entries in each col but also display them (or return them into a list)?

Answer (score 4):

I find the `describe()` function from the `Hmisc` package very handy to get an overview on a dataset, e.g.,

```
Hmisc::describe(chickwts)
```

> ```
> chickwts 
>
>  2  Variables      71  Observations
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> weight 
>        n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd      .05      .10      .25      .50      .75      .90 
>       71        0       66        1    261.3    90.26    140.5    153.0    204.5    258.0    323.5    359.0 
>      .95 
>    385.0 
>
> lowest : 108 124 136 140 141, highest: 380 390 392 404 423
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> feed 
>        n  missing distinct 
>       71        0        6 
>
> Value         casein horsebean   linseed  meatmeal   soybean sunflower
> Frequency         12        10        12        11        14        12
> Proportion     0.169     0.141     0.169     0.155     0.197     0.169
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```