# How do I mutate all columns in a data set to keep only distinct values?

Tags: r, dplyr

Considering the data `mtcars`

something like

```r
mtcars %>% select(mpg,cyl,disp,hp) %>% mutate_all(distinct())
```

I want to have all the distinct values only, I understand this will make the length of data- frame column unequal, so I wanted to also know if we can insert NAs for that?

in short, I want to apply unique() across all columns separately without having to write something like unique(mtcars$cyl) for each of the rows. This will make the length of df unequal,

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you but if you just want the distinct combination of those variables present within mtcars, you can just call `distinct(mtcars, mpg, cyl, disp, hp)`

Comment: `mutate` is for adding or modifying the values in columns. `distinct` is not that, it is a row filtering operation. `distinct()` is it's own verb that acts on a whole data frame, not inside other `dplyr` functions like `mutate()`

Comment: you are right, but using distinct(mtcars, mpg, cyl, disp, hp) will not give me distinct values of mtcars AND mpg AND cyl AND so on, it will return rows which have distinct values as a combination of these attributes. What I'm looking for is to get output like this without having to write "select distinct(row) " for each row: mpg = [1] 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 13.3 27.3 26.0
[23] 15.8 19.7 15.0 , cyl = 6 4 8

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/38961144/680068

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution:

```
lapply(mtcars, unique)
```

Here, `unique()` accepts a vector `x` and returns a (possibly shorter) vector consisting of the unique values. As you noted, the lengths of each unique collection will differ, so we use `lapply()` to obtain the answer as a list.

Given what I think you're trying to do, this might be a more sensible approach than padding `NA` entries, because it seems like the only thing you want is the list of unique values.

Comment: perfect, i was doing something like this lapply(mtcars, unique()) and it was not working, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correct you are looking for this:
To achieve your aim first transform the dataframe columns to list of vectors.
Then replace the duplicates with NA to get the same length and wrap it around `map_dfr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(mpg,cyl,disp,hp) %>% 
  as.list() %>% 
  map_dfr(~replace(., duplicated(.), NA))
```

```
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21       6  160    110
 2  NA      NA   NA     NA
 3  22.8     4  108     93
 4  21.4    NA  258     NA
 5  18.7     8  360    175
 6  18.1    NA  225    105
 7  14.3    NA   NA    245
 8  24.4    NA  147.    62
 9  NA      NA  141.    95
10  19.2    NA  168.   123
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: This is a good alternative, it is keeping relationship rowwise and keeping the unique values per column. OP might want to run `lapply(res, na.omit)` in case they want to have a list of unique values per columns with different lengths.